# Añadir texto en el centro de una gráfica de dona

Tags: r, plot

Tuve problemas desde ayer, en descansos del trabajo, para encontrar la forma de insertar dentro de una gráfica de dona el porcentaje correspondiente a la misma. Por ejemplo, si estoy evaluando las materias de Español y Matemáticas, quisiera hacer una gráfica de dona para cada materia donde se muestre el porcentaje del grupo evaluado (yo estoy haciendo reportes de escuelas), en mi archivo Excel tengo el porcentaje de aciertos y para la otra parte de la dona hago la resta contra el 100%.
El código que tomé de internet y que sirve con BERT.graphics.device (para seleccionar las celdas en Excel a graficar) es el siguiente:

```
###
## Gráfica de dona
###
### Ignorar los colores en col=c(), aún no depuro esa parte
graph.dona <- function(values, clockwise=TRUE, origin.degrees=0,
    radius=1, thickness=0.4, frame.plot=F, xlim=c(-radius, radius),
    ylim=c(-radius, radius), col=c("#A4DBB5","#8BDCA5","#66DE8C","#3DD86E","#DBA4A4","#DC8B8B","#DE6666","#D83D3D"),
    n=2500,centre.text=NULL, centre.cex=par('cex'), centre.col='black', centre.bold=T,
    labels=names(values), labels.cex=par('cex'), labels.col='black', fontface="bold",
    labels.radius=radius-thickness/2, to.degrees=360, main="Resultados", ...) {
    
    BERT.graphics.device(cell=T);

    stopifnot(to.degrees>0 && to.degrees<=360)
    stopifnot(radius > 0)
    stopifnot(thickness > 0 && thickness <= radius)
    stopifnot(n >= 4)

    # n complex numbers
    outer <- complex(modulus=radius, argument=seq(0, 2 * pi * to.degrees / 360,
                                                  length.out=n))

    # Zero degrees is at 12 o'clock, positive numbers are clockwise
    outer <- outer * complex(argument=(ifelse(clockwise, 1, -1) * origin.degrees -
                                       90 + ifelse(clockwise, 0, 1) * 180) * 2 * pi/360)
    if (clockwise) {
        outer <- Conj(outer)
    }

    inner <- outer  * (radius - thickness)

    par(mar = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1))
    #x <- unlist( as.numeric( values ));
    plot(values, axes="F", xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, frame.plot=frame.plot, type='n', xlab="",
         ylab="", xaxt="n", yaxt="n")

    # Ensure a circle
    pin <- par("pin")
    y.multiplier <- pin[1] / pin[2]

    # Matrix of coordinates for the inner and outer circles
    coords <- cbind(outer.x=Re(outer),
                    outer.y=Im(outer) * y.multiplier,
                    inner.x=Re(inner),
                    inner.y=Im(inner) * y.multiplier)

    # Breakpoints into the matrix of coordinates
    breaks <- c(1, round(n * cumsum(values) / sum(values), 0))

    col <- if(is.null(col)) 1+1:length(values) else col

    for(index in 2:length(breaks)) {
        lower <- index-1
        polygon(x=c(coords[breaks[lower]:breaks[index], 'outer.x'],
                    coords[breaks[index]:breaks[lower], 'inner.x']),
                y=c(coords[breaks[lower]:breaks[index], 'outer.y'],
                    coords[breaks[index]:breaks[lower], 'inner.y']), 
                col=col[lower], border=NA, ...)
    }

    if(!is.null(centre.text)) {
        text(0, 0, centre.text, cex=centre.cex, col=centre.col, ...)
    }

    labels.coords <- outer[round(head(breaks, -1) + diff(breaks)/2, 0)] * labels.radius
    labels.coords <- cbind(x=Re(labels.coords), y=Im(labels.coords) * y.multiplier)
    if(!is.null(labels)) {
        text(labels.coords, labels=labels, col=labels.col, cex=labels.cex, ...)
    }

    invisible(list(coords=coords, 
                   breaks=breaks,
                   labels=labels.coords))
  T
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice fue añadir el siguiente código, que me permite buscar en values la primera columna y primera fila donde tengo el número que me interesa que sea representado en la gráfica (la cantidad de aciertos):

```
    ## Añadir texto en el centro de la dona (con porcentaje)
    value <- values[1,1]
    percent <- function(value, format = "f"){
      paste0(formatC(value), "%")
    }
    valuep <- value*100
    legend(-0.55, 0.22, percent(round(valuep)), box.col = NA,
    bg = NA, adj = 0.2, cex=1.5)
```

1. values se compone de dos celdas en mi archivo Excel, A1 y A2 (para
   ejemplificar), en A1 tengo el porcentaje de aciertos y en A2 tengo
   el resultado de restarle al 100% el valor de A1.
2. Me interesa que se grafique values con ambos valores
3. Me interesa que en el centro de la dona aparezca el valor de A1 solamente (value), por eso recurrí a value <- values[1,1]
4. En legend ajusté manualmente los primeros dos valores (-0.55, 0.22) ya que al cambiar el tamaño de la dona se movía el texto del centro.